# pointer class function not printing output?

Tags: c++, c++11

//  i am trying to make array of 
        //pointer class node (table) and print its 
        //   function print_val() but it keeps giving me an error i don't 
        //  understand
    ==================================================================

```
#include<iostream>


using namespace std;

class node {
    int val;
    node *next;
    public:

    node(int x){
        val=x;
        next=NULL;
    } 

    void print_val(){
        cout<<val;
    }

};


int main(){

    //node *table;
    node *object=new node(5);
    node **table=new node*[7];
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
        int x;
        cin>>x;
        node *temp=new node(x);
        table[i]=temp;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<7;++i){
        cout<<table[i]->print_val();
    }
    object->print_val();

    //table=new node[7];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: 1)error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘void’)
      cout<<table[i]->print_val();

Comment: @IshaanKalsi that reply belongs as part of the question

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=0;i<7;++i){
                cout<<table[i]->print_val();
```

In above statement `table[i]->print_val()`, `cout` expecting one **integer** value but `print_val()` not returning. Modify the `print_val()` function as

```
int  print_val(){
                cout<<val;
                return val;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong

```
cout << table[i]->print_val();
```

you're passing to cout void which is the return value of your function

it should be

```
table[i]->print_val();
```